# Having trouble using JWT with a custom User model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I've started a new Django project and like the documentation recommends I've created a custom user model just in case it's needed and made sure to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

I notice that when you do this you cannot run `python manage.py makemigrations` you actually have to specify the app the custom user model is in `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>`. Once I do that I'm able to start the server.

I followed this post to integrate JWT into my new project: [Django React JWT](https://medium.com/@dakota.lillie/django-react-jwt-authentication-5015ee00ef9a)

Without the custom user model the post works great but once I add in a custom user model I start getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/repos/api/core/views.py", line 30, in post
    if serializer.is_valid():
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 236, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 434, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 482, in to_internal_value
    fields = self._writable_fields
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 370, in _writable_fields
    field for field in self.fields.values() if not field.read_only
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 363, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1019, in get_fields
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(model)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py", line 39, in get_field_info
    forward_relations = _get_forward_relationships(opts)
  File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-RqAznZCl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py", line 96, in _get_forward_relationships
    not field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Seems like ti has something to do with the serializer as I used pdb to trace and the token was being generated but the user object that is passed back isn't being serialized properly...

Comment: Can you show your serializers and views?

Comment: Anything here, I am getting the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the djangorestframework-jwt library takes `User` model from `get_user_model`, so make sure you have `AUTH_USER_MODEL` pointing to your custom user model class.